# Kotlin Gradle driver dependency not found

Tags: sql, kotlin, gradle, dependencies

I've been trying to write a gradle task which will execute some SQL.

When executing the task it fails with:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'xyz'.
> Could not create task ':resetDatabase'.
   > com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

with stacktrace enabled I can see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

The relevant bits of my build.gradle.kts look like:

```
import java.util.*
import java.io.FileInputStream
import groovy.sql.Sql

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.2.0.jre8")
}

val resetDatabase = tasks.register("resetDatabase") {
    val properties = Properties()
    properties.load(FileInputStream(file("./webBasedPortal.properties")))

    val sqlToExecute = File("./clearDatabase.sql").readText()

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

    val sql = Sql.newInstance(
        properties.getProperty("db.url"),
        properties.getProperty("db.user"),
        properties.getProperty("db.password")
    )
    sql.execute(sqlToExecute)
}
```

Comment: Note: com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.2.0.jre8 is an external library in this project, but even when I downloaded the jar and did `implementation(files("lib/mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre11.jar"))` in the dependencies, I got the same error.

Comment: See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies